# function does not proces input argument in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have a dataset that consists of 82 columns.

I am trying to write a function, that takes a column name as argument (x) and then coverts the names in that column to a number. Per column the number of unique names differs.

sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(column_1 = 1:10, column_2 = c("MT", "BM", "KA", "MT", "BM", "KA","MT", "BM", "KA", "MT"))
```

The result I expected was that this function converts column_2 to:

1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1

When I tested the body of the function, it does what it is supposed to do:
1) apply the function only when it is character and there are no NA's
2) select the unique values
3) substitute that unique value for a number ranging from 1 to n

```
UniekeNamen <- unique(VolledigeSet$MSZoning)
VervangenVoor <- c(1:length(VolledigeSet$MSZoning))
if (is.character(VolledigeSet$MSZoning) & sum(is.na(VolledigeSet$MSZoning) == 0)) {
  for (i in seq_along(UniekeNamen)) {
    VolledigeSet$MSZoning[VolledigeSet$MSZoning == UniekeNamen[i]] <- VervangenVoor[i]
  }
}
```

But when I encapsule the body in a function, and substitute the column names for the argument x, the function does not work as if the argument isn't recognized. There is no error message, just nothing happens...

This is the function i wrote:

```
name2num <- function(x) {
  UniekeNamen <- unique(x)
  VervangenVoor <- c(1:length(UniekeNamen))
  if (is.character(x) & sum(is.na(x) == 0)) {
   for (i in seq_along(UniekeNamen)) {
     x[x == UniekeNamen[i]] <- VervangenVoor[i]
   }
  }
}
```

Do you have a suggestion what to change to the function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Main issue is the function doesn't have a `return` value... working on an answer.

Comment: Just a hint: If you convert `column_2` into a `factor` (`df$column_2 <- as.factor(df$column_2)`, you'll be able to get your result by using `levels(df$column_2) <- 1:length(levels(df$column_2))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that your function needs to `return` the complete modified `x`. You can do this by putting `x` or `return(x)` as the last line of the function.

When I fix the return issue and run the function on your sample data `df$column_2` is unmodified because that column is a factor, not a character (as I haven't yet upgraded to R 4.0), so I demonstrate it coercing `column_2` to character.

That would get us this function:

```
name2num <- function(x) {
  UniekeNamen <- unique(x)
  VervangenVoor <- c(1:length(UniekeNamen))
  if (is.character(x) & sum(is.na(x) == 0)) {
   for (i in seq_along(UniekeNamen)) {
     x[x == UniekeNamen[i]] <- VervangenVoor[i]
   }
  }
  x
}

name2num(as.character(df$column_2))
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "1" "2" "3" "1" "2" "3" "1"
```

Note that, because the elements of the column are changed one-at-a-time, the class of the column stays the same. If you want the output to be numeric, not character, you should have the function return `as.numeric(x)`.

We can improve the function by leaning on R's `factor` class, which already does this pretty well. This will be vectorized and more efficient. It will also let the function work on `factor` columns since the conversion is all-at-once, rather than one-element-at-a-time.

```
name2num_gt = function(x) {
  if ((is.character(x) | is.factor(x)) & sum(is.na(x) == 0)) {
    x = as.integer(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))
  }
  x
}
name2num_gt(as.character(df$column_2))
# [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1
```

There are many ways to apply this to all columns in your data. One option would be `df[] = lapply(df, name2num_gt)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the vector of the output which in turn needs to be applied to the existing data set by replacement.

```
name2num <- function(x) {
  UniekeNamen <- unique(x)
  VervangenVoor <- c(1:length(UniekeNamen))
  if (is.character(x) !=0 & sum(is.na(x) == 0)) {
    for (i in seq_along(UniekeNamen)) {
      x[x == UniekeNamen[i]] <- VervangenVoor[i]
    }
    return(as.factor(x))
  }
}


df$column_2 <- name2num(df$column_2)
df
```

Output:

```
   column_1 column_2
1         1        1
2         2        2
3         3        3
4         4        1
5         5        2
6         6        3
7         7        1
8         8        2
9         9        3
10       10        1
```

P.S.: If you want to have column_2 as numeric, use `return(as.numeric(x))` instead